# DIV set to overflow:scroll, but wont scroll all the way to bottom

Tags: html, css, html-lists, overflow

I have a ***DIV*** menu that is set to 100% height with a ***overflow:scroll***.  Within the ***DIV*** I have a ***ul li***. The problem I have is that it wont let me scroll all the way down to see the last ***li***. I can barely see it.

I think it has something to do with my ***header*** because when I remove the header, I can see it. When I put back the header, it goes under the browser and cannot be scrolled all the way down to see the last ***li***.

Both ***li*** and header are almost identical in height and it makes a lot of sense that the header is causing the problem. Not the header in particular, I think, but more of something I did in CSS.

Why cant I scroll all the way to the bottom? What is the solution?

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/D5KU3/2/

```
<div class="container">

<!--header-->
 <div class="header">
 </div>
<!--end header-->

<!--left-->
 <div class="left">

<!--ul starts here-->

  <ul>

  <li class="hybrid">

    <a href="#">
    <p class="title">Why Cant</p>
    <p class="type">I scroll all the way to the bottom</p></a>

  </li>
```

Repeat ***li*** 20 times

```
  </ul> <!--ul ends here-->

  </div> <!--container ends here-->
```

CSS

```
  body, html {
  height:100%;  
  }

  body {
  background:white;

  }

  .container {
  width:260px;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:silver;
  margin:0 auto;
  font-family:sintony;
  }

  .header {
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  background:#000;
  }

  .left {
  width:260px;
  height:100%;
  background:#fff;
  float:left;
  overflow:scroll;
  }


 li.hybrid a {
 display:block;
 background:#16BF14;
 height:60px;
 width:260px;
 text-decoration:none;
 position:relative;
 }



 li.purple a {
 display:block;
 background:#3370CC;
 height:60px;
 width:260px;
 text-decoration:none;
 position:relative;
 }

 p.title {
 position:relative;
 padding-left:10px;
 }

 p.type {
 font-size:12px;
 position:relative;
 padding-left:10px;
 }

 ul {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }

 li p {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style-type:none;
 }
```

Comment: You should choose an answer mate! They spent time for you to reply

Answer (score 13):

As you have both the `class="header"` and `class="left"` elements in the container, and the `class="left"` element is 100% of the container, those are 100% plus 60 pixels together.

You can make room for the header by using `box-sizing` and `padding-top` in the container. That will make the inner size of the container 100% minus 60 pixels. Then use a negative top margin on the header to place it on top of that padding:

```
.container {
    box-sizing: padding-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: padding-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: padding-box;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.header {
    margin-top: -60px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/D5KU3/11/

You might also want to get rid of the page margin, otherwise the 100% container and the margin is taller than the window:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Great solution. You saved me...! Thanks. But, to be honest, I don't understand how can this work.

Comment: @MaRco85: By changing the `box-sizing` you can set the height to 100% while still have a padding. The padding will reduce the area inside the container where a scrolling element can be placed, and the header can be placed in the room created by the padding so that it doesn't interfer with the scrolling element.

Comment: Oh, I have forgot, the right attribute name is: "box-sizing: border-box;" you can correct your answer maybe :-) - Thanks for explanation anyway. Need to study that for sure

Comment: @MaRco85: It's a different value, not a typo.`padding-box` and `border-box` differ in whether the border is inlcuded. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: `border-box`  is now the widely accepted standard, and `padding-box` is deprecated.

Comment: You're a wizard, Guffa!

Answer (score -1):

It's actually quite logic - you have your body and html set to 100%. This means the content of the body can't be higher then the available space in your browser - and so you don't see the bottom.

If you remove this CSS the problem is solved; although it might be better to set the body to `min-height: 100%`. This way the height of the page will always be the complete available space; unless it's content is more than that.

An updates jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D5KU3/3/

Comment: Wrong. Cause in his case he does not want to exceed the height of the page (100%).

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `overflow: hidden;` from `.container` class

```
.container {
  width:260px;
  height:100%;
  background:silver;
  margin:0 auto;
  font-family:sintony;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/atYpX/

Comment: The problem is not this. We don't want to exceed the 100% height of the page so hiding the overflow is fine.

Comment: This was definitely my problem.   My global style had overflow:hidden.

Answer (score -1):

i would recommend following

```
.left {
  position:absolute;
  width:260px;
  top:60px;
  height:100%;
  background:#fff; 
  overflow:scroll;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D5KU3/8/

Comment: Why would you use an absolute position?